# Orbit of Lagrange resolvent under complex conjugation

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, galois-theory

The orbit of Lagrange resolvent $R = \sum{a_i w^i}$ under the action of $S_n$ plays a key role in Lagrange's method of solving polynomial equations. I've been playing with the case n=4 and noticed the following:

- Orbit of simple $R$ has size 24. No surprise here because the $w^i$ are linearly independent.
- Orbit of $R^4$ has size 6. Again no surprise because $R^4 = (w^i R)^4$ for each $i = 0, 1, 2, 3$.
- Taking complex conjugation, the orbit of $(R \bar{R})^4$ has size 3 because the complex conjugation automorphism has order 2 in the Galois group.

The surprise came when I noticed that also the orbit of just $R \bar{R}$ has size 3, and similar observations can be made for other n, e.g. 5. I would expect that according to arguments above the orbit would have size $n!/2$. There must apparently be a hidden structure in the resolvent that I don't see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's not exactly correct to say that $w^i$s are linearly independent over the base field, e.g. trivially $\sum{w^i} = 0$. Nevertheless, this doesn't affect the orbit of $R$.

Anyway, there is a similar action of the roots of unity as in the second point, namely that $w^iR*w^{n-i}\bar{R} = R\bar{R}$ for each $i = 1, \ldots, n$. That explains why the orbit size of $R\bar{R}$ is $n!/2n$.